# Backup Ubuntu + Apache + Postfix (no bash)

Tags: server, apache2, backup, postfix

My company has 10 laptops and a server with Ubuntu onboard. There are also Apache and Postfix on it. I'm totally new to Ubuntu (I have never used it and I believe I have no need to try it). But for the moment my company have fired our admin and I have to take a look for the server.

Could you suggest me an idea of how to backup the described infrastructure with minimum efforts (something like windows-style several clicks backup). Please don't address to Google as the most solutions there use bash and I have never used it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard backup program on ubuntu.
Just type "backup" in the dash menu to find it

(See picture. Thats the dash icon. Click on it and type backup)

Works for very well for me.

[image]